# Permissions error running Java Timezone Updater JAR in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a fairly standard Java image with some dependencies added in that I'm writing this Dockerfile on top of. Here's where I'm having a problem in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN which java
RUN ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "tzupdater.jar", "-v", "-l"]
```

I thought that every Dockerfile command was run as root? But when I try to build from this Dockerfile, I'm running into this permissions issue which also happened in my local environment when I forgot to run this JAR as `sudo`:

```
$ docker build -t container-w-tz-update .
Uploading context 1.122 GB
Uploading context 
Step 0 : FROM company/java-img-with-dependencies:1.0
 ---> 0101010101
...
Step 3 : RUN which java
 ---> Running in 0101010101
/usr/bin/java
 ---> 0101010101
Step 4 : RUN ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "tzupdater.jar", "-v", "-l"]
 ---> Running in 0101010101
java.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.version: 1.6.0_45
tzupdater version 2.1.1-b01
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata.tar.gz
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp/sha512hash
failed.
Cant rename {0} to {1}.
com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: Cant rename {0} to {1}.

Caused by: com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: Cant rename {0} to {1}.
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.update(TimezoneUpdater.java:301)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:249)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:643)
2017/04/05 22:20:23 The command [/usr/bin/java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I was able to run this utility as `sudo` on my local with the exact same version of Java with no issues. When I tried to run it locally without `sudo`, I received the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please post your Dockerfile of base image? And what will `tzupdater.jar` actually do?

Comment: @shizhz tzupdater.jar is a utility provided by Oracle to update time zone data in the Java standard libraries. It should work on Java 1.5 through 1.8. I'll post a full Dockerfile at work tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your info and sorry for lack of knowledge of `tzupdater.jar`, I'll have a try to see if I can reproduce your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

*(This is more like a comment but the message length is beyond the comment limit, so I leave it here as an answer so that other people can maybe give more useful info based on what I've done.)*

Seems it's really an unresolved issue, I  reproduced your problem by image `enoniccloud/java6` running with `root` user, I also tried `docker run -it --privileged ...` to run it manually but it does not help. I also tried `jdk8` with base image `alpine:3.3` but also failed with:

```
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp/sha512hash
Renaming /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/tzdb.dat to /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/tzdb.dat.tzdata2016a failed.
Cant rename {0} to {1}.
Validating for : tzdata2017b
Validation complete
JRE updated to version : tzdata2017b
```

I searched and the only info I found is as follows:

- An open issue: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/896
- Related but not the same: https://forums.docker.com/t/update-docker-container-jre-to-set-timezone-correctly/24426

Before you find the root cause for this issue, I think an alternative way to build your image could be:

- Download a JDK tarball for your platform
- Untar it, setup `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`, run `java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l` on your host
- Build your base image based on this updated JDK, `ADD` to image and setup environment variable like `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`

Hope this could be helpful to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

`docker build` will complete `RUN` steps as the last `USER` set in the Dockerfile.

To reset:

```
RUN whoami
USER root
RUN ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "tzupdater.jar", "-v", "-l"]
USER "whatever whoami reported"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for that. Adding some `mv` commands (that have no real effect) made it work:

```
FROM openjdk:7u211-jdk-alpine3.9

ADD tzupdater.jar tzupdater.jar

RUN mv /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre/lib/zi /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre/lib/zi.tzdata2018g && \
    mv /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre/lib/zi.tzdata2018g /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre/lib/zi && \
    java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l https://.../tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

I have no idea why it works, I got it by trial and error.

Notice the two `mv` commands do like `mv a b && mv b a`, so nothing really changes.

The names of the files (dirs, actually) used in the `mv` are the ones it outputs when it errors (before the workaround), so change it accordingly.